# How do I draw a line from point to point on this 3x3 grid?

Tags: tikz-matrix

How do I draw a line connecting a dot from one end to another?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{matrix}
\bullet & \bullet & \bullet \\
\bullet & \bullet & \bullet \\
\bullet & \bullet & \bullet \\
\end{matrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: between bullet in the first and last column or row? just one arrow? Please clarify! One way id use `tikzmark` library of `tikz`, another is write matrix in  with `tikz` and than draw lines between selected bullets.

Comment: The first bullet is on the top left and a line is drawn horizontally to the bullet on the bottom left. I'm not familiar with ``` tikzmark``` can you provide some code? Thank you.

Comment: How would I make this 3x3 grid on tikz?

Comment: See my answer (how to use `tikz`).

Comment: Any news? Does answer solve your problem? If yes, you may consider at least upvote it or even to accept it (by clicking on the check mark at top left side of answer). BTW, as I see, so far you not accept any from received answers. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Just guessing ... with tikz` you can write you matrix as:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,
             nodes={inner sep=-0.5pt, outer sep=-0pt},
             column sep=1ex, row sep=1ex
             ]
{ 
\bullet & \bullet & \bullet \\
\bullet & \bullet & \bullet \\
\bullet & \bullet & \bullet \\
};
\draw[red] (m-1-1) -- (m-1-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or like this -- bullets are drawn as nodes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes,
             nodes in empty cells,
             nodes={circle, fill, inner sep= 1pt, outer sep=0pt},
             column sep=1ex, row sep=1ex
             ]
{ 
    &   &   \\
    &   &   \\
    &   &   \\
};
\draw[red] (m-1-1) to[bend left] (m-1-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]